# Google maps static displaying in Firefox but not in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-maps

I have this html code (image tag) that I use to display location using Google chrome static API

```
<img src="http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=45.49558919270833,15.543660481770834&amp;zoom=14&amp;size=475x390&amp;maptype=mobile&amp;markers=45.49558919270833,15.543660481770834,blue&amp;key=ABQIAAAAdco5_H7LOM9g_zpERCDbTRRjR6gPnoGgGJLZeHh5-ndhggJYMxRqh1xqSx3d-C6qdRvNoh0KewGWLw">
```

But it displays in Firefox but not in Chrome ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error, missing closed img tag